# TSQL - Get value between dates in data warehouse dimension

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have the beginnngs of a data warehouse, that contains (among other tables)

- date table with 200 years worth of dates to join with, so no need to
  build a "dynamic" date table
- dbo.Dim_Items (see below)

| ItemNumber | QOH | EffectiveDate | ExpirationDate | IsCurrentRecord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 372620 | 24 | 2021-12-11 05:34:09.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 372620 | 11 | 2021-12-09 05:34:11.000 | 2021-12-11 05:34:09.000 | 0 |
| 372620 | 9 | 2021-12-07 05:34:20.000 | 2021-12-09 05:34:11.000 | 0 |

I would like to find the QOH for each day between 2021-12-07 and today (assume 2021-12-13, for brevity), so that my result looks like this

| Date | ItemNumber | QOH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-07 | 372620 | 9 |
| 2021-12-08 | 372620 | 9 |
| 2021-12-09 | 372620 | 11 |
| 2021-12-10 | 372620 | 11 |
| 2021-12-11 | 372620 | 24 |
| 2021-12-12 | 372620 | 24 |
| 2021-12-13 | 372620 | 24 |

The closest I have come is the query below, but it is not working the way I want it to (note the zeros on dates that don't line up with the Items dimension)

```
DECLARE @START_DATE date,
        @END_DATE date

SET @START_DATE = '20211207'
SET @END_DATE = GETDATE()   -- '20211213'

SELECT CAL.TheDate,
        I.ItemNumber,
        I.QOH
FROM dbo.Dim_Calendar CAL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Items I ON CAL.TheDate >= CAST(I.EffectiveDate as date)
        AND CAL.TheDate <= CAST(I.EffectiveDate as date)
        AND I.ItemNumber = 372620
WHERE CAL.TheDate >= @START_DATE
    AND CAL.TheDate <= @END_DATE
ORDER BY CAL.TheDate,
            I.ItemNumber
```

| Date | ItemNumber | QOH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-07 | 372620 | 9 |
| 2021-12-08 | 372620 | 0 |
| 2021-12-09 | 372620 | 11 |
| 2021-12-10 | 372620 | 0 |
| 2021-12-11 | 372620 | 24 |
| 2021-12-12 | 372620 | 0 |
| 2021-12-13 | 372620 | 0 |

I am new to data warehousing as a whole, so I am not sure how to build this query correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c583ca3cfb4a987a176d79f4689a6923)

```
DECLARE @START_DATE date,
        @END_DATE date

SET @START_DATE = '20211207'
SET @END_DATE = GETDATE()   -- '20211213'

SELECT
   TheDate,
   I.Itemnumber,
   I.QOH
FROM dbo.Dim_Calendar CAL
LEFT JOIN dbo.Dim_Items I On CAL.TheDate BETWEEN CAST(I.EffectiveDate as DATE) 
                                             AND I.ExpirationDate
                         AND I.Itemnumber = 372620
WHERE CAL.TheDate >= @START_DATE
    AND CAL.TheDate <= @END_DATE
ORDER BY CAL.TheDate,
            I.ItemNumber
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something simple